# typescript namespace declaration using a reserved name

Tags: typescript, types

I am making an `Http` client. The typescript definition for this would look something like:

```
declare namespace Http {
   type HttpOptions = ...;
   type HttpPromise<T> = ...

   function get<T>(url: string, options?: HttpOptions): HttpPromise<T>;
   function delete<T>(url: string, options?: HttpOptions): HttpPromise<T>;
}
```

The `delete` here now is yelling because this is a reserved word. But I do have a method `Http.delete('/foo')` on my module.

How do i declare that dependency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm guessing you don't want to hear "don't do that", but that's probably the best advice.  Using [reserved words](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#221-reserved-words) as identifiers isn't *guaranteed* to fail, but you shouldn't be surprised if some JavaScript environment somewhere balks at it.  But never mind, we're going ahead with it.

---

So this is a bit of a strange one.  I'd *like* to use a quoted string literal [the way you can with a method or property name](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/blob/master/doc/spec.md#222-property-names), as mentioned in the TypeScript spec:

> String literals may be used to give properties names that are not valid identifiers

But that doesn't work for *function* names, which must be valid identifiers.

One thing you can apparently do is give the function a valid name and then [export an alias to it](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#export-statements):

```
declare namespace Http {
  export type HttpOptions = ...
  export type HttpPromise<T> = ...
  export function get<T>(url: string, options?: HttpOptions): HttpPromise<T>;
  function del<T>(url: string, options?: HttpOptions): HttpPromise<T>;  
  export { del as delete }; // no error
}
```

I say you can "apparently" do it because I can't find any documentation that indicates one way or another.  I would have thought that the reserved word would fail in the `as` clause (and you can't quote it there either; `del as "delete"` is an error), but it seems to work:

```
Http.get('url') // okay
Http.delete('url') // apparently okay but you probably shouldn't
Http['delete']('url') // okay
```

Does that help?

---

Another idea is to use [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html), but again [I'm kind of surprised it works](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/18163).  First declare the namespace with only the type aliases, and then merge in a declared constant of the same name with the properties.  It's fragile and weird but it also works for me:

```
declare namespace Http {
  export type HttpOptions = ...
  export type HttpPromise<T> = ...
}
declare const Http: {
  get<T>(url: string, options?: Http.HttpOptions): Http.HttpPromise<T>;
  "delete"<T>(url: string, options?: Http.HttpOptions): Http.HttpPromise<T>;  
}
```

Hope one of those works for you; good luck!

Comment: I'll try your second approach. I specifically writing a custom wrapper for the https://github.com/axios/axios library. So the `delete` function already exists. I can create an alias `del` or `remove` or something but rather not.

Comment: Exporting aliases is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!